# Let $(X, Y )$ be a random pair with the density $f(x,y) = c(y-x)^2, 0<x<y<1$ and $0, elsewhere$ for some constant $c > 0$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, density-function

> Let $(X, Y)$ be a random pair with the density 
>   $$
> f(x,y) = 
> \begin{cases}
> c(y-x)^2, & 0<x<y<1\\
> 0,        & \text{elsewhere}
> \end{cases}
> $$ for some constant $c > 0$. Find $c$.

So far I'm assuming I integrate like so $\int_{0}^{x}$ $\int_{y}^{1}$ ${c(y-x)^2 dydx}$ but I'm not exactly where where to go from here.

Answer (score 2):

**hint**

you need to set up the integration correctly.
from your bounds, you can take the inner integral varying $y$ from $x$ to $1$, and the outer integral varies $x$ from $0$, can you find to what upper limit? then integration yields

$$
1 = c \int_0^{???} \int_x^1 (y-x)^2 dy dx
$$

and if you integrate it becomes an arithmetic problem.

Comment: Aww yes I see where I messed up. Should be 0 to y

Comment: @Slae no :) the upper limit should be constant, otherwise your integral ends up as a function of $y$. Why don't you draw the region to figure out which value to pick?

Comment: @Slae *Hint:* The inner integral "removes" $y$ from consideration.  So where does $x$ live when you don't have to accomodate $y$?